# Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle gives ORA-01019 error, can't seem to find the oracle driver

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I'm getting an error trying to connect to an Oracle DB, and I'm pretty sure I have my variables out of whack.

The error I'm getting is

`Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle gives ORA-01019 error, can't seem to find the oracle driver`

My current Environment and System variables are as such:

System Variables:
ORACLE_HOME: `C:\app\MyUser\product\instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0\instantclient_12_2`

I also have a Path variable reference: Same path `C:\app\MyUser\product\instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0\instantclient_12_2`

I do not have a reference to the Oracle client in my User Variables, though.

Comment: Not my area, but isn't Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle)? Can you use the Oracle-supplied ODBC driver instead?

Comment: Which application do you use? In case of 64-bit you have to use the Oracle ODBC driver. Microsoft ODBC driver exist only for 32-bit.

Comment: Try to add also `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin` to `PATH`

Comment: Links to resources are off-topic of course, but if you don't already have it - I guess not from the name of your directory - you can get the ODBC driver from the same place you got [the rest of the Instant Client files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html). Or depending on your application, you may need [the 64-bit versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html). (There isn't a `bin` sub directory with Instant Client, but you may need some other setup still).

Comment: I'm using Excel 32-bit, so I installed 32-bit Oracle Client